# How to test with Rspec that a key exists inside a hash that contains an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I have a Model method that returns the following when executed.

```
 {"data" => [
 {"product" => "PRODUCTA", "orders" => 3, "ordered" => 6, "revenue" => 600.0},
 {"product" => "PRODUCTB", "orders" => 1, "ordered" => 5, "revenue" => 100.0}]}
```

I would like to test to make sure that "revenue" in the first hash is there and then test that the value is equal to 600.

```
subject { described_class.order_items_by_revenue }

it "includes revenue key" do
  expect(subject).to include(:revenue)
end
```

I am completely lost on how to test this with Rspec.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

RSpec allows you to use the [have_key](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers#should-have-key-(based-on-hash#has-key?)) predicate matcher to validate the presence of a key via `has_key?`, like so:

```
subject { described_class.order_items_by_revenue }

it "includes revenue key" do
  expect(subject.first).to have_key(:revenue)
end
```

Comment: I get the following when I try this example --------



          Failure/Error: expect(subject.first).to have_key(:revenue)
       expected ["data", [{"product"=>"PRODUCTA", "orders"=>3, "ordered"=>13596, "revenue"=>600.0}, {"product"=>"PRODUCTB", "orders"=>1, "ordered"=>2568, "revenue"=>100.0}]] to respond to `has_key?`

Comment: You want subject to be `subject { described_class.order_items_by_revenue["data"] }`, or you want to test `subject["data"].first`. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

This issue can be solved via testing of each hash by key existing with appropriate type of value. For example:

```
describe 'GetCatsService' do
  subject { [{ name: 'Felix', age: 25 }, { name: 'Garfield', age: 40 }] }

  it { is_expected.to include(include(name: a_kind_of(String), age: a_kind_of(Integer)))}
end

# GetCatsService
#  should include (include {:name => (a kind of String), :age => (a kind of Integer)})
```

Comment: This is not quite correct, should be:  `it { is_expected.to all match(name: a_kind_of(String), age: a_kind_of(Integer)) }` In your example, if you change `Felix` to the number 1, it will still pass.

Answer (score 7):

If you explicitly want to test **only** the **first hash** in your array mapped to `:data`, here are your `expect`s given what you wrote above:

```
data = subject[:data].first
expect(data).not_to be_nil
expect(data.has_key?(:revenue)).to be_truthy
expect(data[:revenue]).to eq 600
```

Alternatively, for the second expectation, you could use `expect(data).to have_key(:revenue)` as Chris Heald pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379968/2639561) which has a much nicer failure message as seen in the comments.

1. The first "expectation" test if the subject has the *first hash*. (You could alternately test if the array is `empty?`)
2. The next expectation is testing if the *first hash* has the key `:revenue`
3. The last expectation tests if the *first hash* `:revenue` value is equal to 600

You should [read up on RSpec](http://rspec.info/), it's a very powerful and usefull testing framework.

Comment: So i feel a little better because I had actually tried a couple of these. I get the following error when I try the second one in your list.

     Failure/Error: expect(subject.first.has_key?(:revenue)).to be_truthy
     NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for #<Array:0x007fec35b5c830>

Comment: Looks like it should be `subject[:data].first`

Answer (score 2):

this works for me in `'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'`

```rb
array_of_hashes = [
  {
    id: "1356786826",
    contact_name: 'John Doe'
  }
]

expect(array_of_hashes).to include(have_key(:id))
```